# Aws step functions - Resume from failed step function activity instead of starting a new execution

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I created a step function with 4 different activities which run one after other and also integrated to trigger this step function from a java application. Flow looks like this.

> Start -> Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity3 -> Activity4 -> Stop

When an execution fails during some activity, let's say Activity2, the execution is marked as failure.

Now, is there anyway to resume this failed execution from the activity(Activity2) during which it failed earlier instead of starting a new execution?

I went through the operations which are possible through `AWSStepFunctions` but none seem to solve this requirement.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_Operations.html

Answer (score 2):

AWS Step Functions released support to restart execution from failed state with the help of RedriveExecution API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_RedriveExecution.html

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** Now you can use *redrive* feature of AWS Step Functions rolled-out by AWS on 15 Nov 2023.

It will help you to resume/re-execute the failed state from the mid (where it got failed) instead of running the whole state machine from start.

For more information, refer this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-step-functions-redrive-a-new-way-to-restart-workflows/).

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue .

[This is describe in details here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resume-aws-step-functions-from-any-state/)

Parse the execution history of the failed execution to find the name of the state at which it failed, as well as the JSON input to that state.

Create a new state machine, which adds an additional state to failed state machine, called “GoToState”. “GoToState” is a choice state at the beginning of the state machine that branches execution directly to the failed state, allowing you to skip states that had succeeded in the previous execution.

Comment: I don't believe this solution would work for most enterprise software. Where I work we do not have access to dynamically create new state machines in our production environment. All new AWS resources must be deployed through an established CI/CD process - in this example the script would not have access to create a new state machine just to retry an execution

Answer (score 0):

The public documentation for error handling with AWS Step Functions contains a section about [fallback states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html). This allows you to specify logic around handling Task failures, and proceed to another state based on the error observed.

The following Catch field redirects the flow of the execution based on the error observed from the associated Task state:

```
"Catch": [ {
   "ErrorEquals": [ "java.lang.Exception" ],
   "ResultPath": "$.error-info",
   "Next": "RecoveryState"
}, {
   "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
   "Next": "EndState"
} ]
```

Comment: I'm not looking for alternatives or error handling. If a service method used by Activity2 threw some runtime error and the complete execution failed, I would like to fix the issue with service method and re-run the execution from Activity2 avoiding running Activity1 again.

Comment: I find this quite frustrating because the documentation isn't very clear if this is possible or not possible. They tout built-in idempotency but this is a major overlook. Or say you were having a production issue and the next time exponential backoff retries is in a week or month, really inconvenient to not be able to trigger a retry on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this resource, which implements the solution from the blog posted linked by Atharv:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sfn-resume-from-any-state

```
python3 gotostate.py --failedExecutionArn 'my-arn'
```

You use the script to generate a new Step Function that will start off at the failed step. The new Step Function takes the input to the failed step as its input with an additional `"resuming": true` field.